# Як правильно: П.І.Б. чи П.І.П.?

Tags: орфографія, скорочення

При заповненні різних бланків і документів стикалась із варіантами назви графи для заповнення власного прізвища, імені та по батькові "П.І.Б." та "П.І.П.".

Неодноманітність спостерігається і на онлайн ресурсах. Так, [тут](https://mkrada.gov.ua/documents/28145.html) "П.І.П.", а вже [тут](https://pm.zp.court.gov.ua/sud0822/zrazki/zayava2)  варіант "П.І.Б.".

Більше того,т на цьому ж [порталі судової влади](https://kl.cv.court.gov.ua/sud2405/12/2/889/) побачила навіть варіант "п.і.п.б.".

До цієї ж теми, через неодноманітність вживання, незрозуміло, чи потрібні крапки між літерами.

*Зважаючи на те, що google видає обидва варіанти, хотілось би зрозуміти, як таки правильно: "П.І.Б." чи "П.І.П."?*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

На [цьому](https://kak-pravilno.net/pib-chi-pip-yak-pravilno/) сайті пише:

> **ПІБ – єдиний правильний варіант скорочення в українській мові.** Прізвище, ім’я, по батькові скорочуємо саме так, оскільки *скорочення відбувається за першими літерами іменника, а не прийменника*.
>
> Наприклад:
>
> В цьому полі потрібно написати *ПІБ*.

У [Словнику скорочень української мови](http://www.ukrskor.info/?text=%D0%9F%D0%86%D0%91)
та у [Списку абревіатур і скорочень з військової справи](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80_%D1%96_%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C_%D0%B7_%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%97_%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8) теж подають:

> **ПІБ**   - прізвище, імя, по батькові.

Однак в академічних працях інформації як такої про дану проблему, на жаль, не знайшла.